# How to convert a UTC date to NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a string that is UTC and would like to convert it to an NSDate.

```
static NSDateFormatter* _twitter_dateFormatter;
[_twitter_dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[_twitter_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
[_twitter_dateFormatter setLocale:_en_us_locale];

NSDate *d = [_twitter_dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
```

When I go through the debugger d is nil even though sDate is "2010-03-24T02:35:57Z"

Not exactly sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Also just a little nit-pick: d is nil in the debugger not *d (you can't dereference a null pointer).

Comment: Actually, your string is not "UTC". Your 'sDate' string value is the standard format (RFC 3339 or ISO 8601) representing a datetime that happens to be in the Zulu (UTC) time zone (the 'Z' on the end).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ditto on the need to alloc/init your NSDateFormatter object, but you have another problem too: your Date format string does not match the actual date  you're giving it.

```
"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"
- vs -
"2010-03-24T02:35:57Z"
```

That format string would match something like:

```
"Wed Mar 24 00:07:33 -0400 2010"
```

See the [unicode standard](http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-4.html#Date_Format_Patterns) for the meaning of the date format string.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the mismatch. I'm not sure how I can format the string to be like "2010-03-24T02:35:57Z"

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263455/nil-nsdate-when-trying-to-get-date-from-utc-string-in-zulu-time
In particular, note the suggestion that you may want to replace the final "Z" in the input string with an explicit numeric timezone (-0000)

Comment: Thanks! In my case the date format should be yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ Replacing Z with (-0000) did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't allocating or initialising your NSDateFormatter object.

Try something like this:

```
NSDateFormatter* _twitter_dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[_twitter_dateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehaviorDefault];
[_twitter_dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss ZZZ yyyy"];
[_twitter_dateFormatter setLocale:_en_us_locale];

NSDate *d = [_twitter_dateFormatter dateFromString:sDate];
[_twitter_dateFormatter release];
```

It's also unclear why you are declaring _twitter_dateFormatter as a static.  If you are trying to avoid re-allocating it, make it an ivar of your class.

Answer (score 0):

Apple gives source code for [Parsing an RFC 3339 date-time](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1480/_index.html). If using ARC, you'll may want to adjust that source by removing the calls to 'autorelease'.

FYI, [RFC 3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt) is a subset of [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) with [one deviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601_usage) (negative zero offset is allowed in RFC 3339). So Apple’s code is killing two birds with one stone, handling the so-called 'Internet-style' RFC 3339 datetimes as well as simple datetimes of ISO 8601.