# Incorrectly formatting an NSDate from string

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I would like to create an NSDate from a string:

```
NSString *mostRecentMentionMessageTimestamp = [mostRecentMessage valueForKey:@"updated_at"];
NSLog(@"%@",mostRecentMentionMessageTimestamp);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ"];
NSDate *mostRecentMentionDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:mostRecentMentionMessageTimestamp];
NSLog(@"%@",mostRecentMentionDate);
```

When I print my string it is:
2011-11-10T07:22:59Z

After I make a date from string and print it, it is `(null)`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert a UTC date to NSDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2504992/how-to-convert-a-utc-date-to-nsdate)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format is almost correct, use:

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
```

to solve the time zone issue use the solution by @Jef add:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"UTC"]];
```

Full example code:

```
NSString *mostRecentMentionMessageTimestamp = @"2011-11-10T07:22:59Z";
NSLog(@"input:  %@",mostRecentMentionMessageTimestamp);
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init]; 
[dateFormatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *mostRecentMentionDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:mostRecentMentionMessageTimestamp];
NSLog(@"output: %@",mostRecentMentionDate);
```

NSLog output:

```
input:  2011-11-10T07:22:59Z
output: 2011-11-10 07:22:59 +0000
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the time zone and drop the `Z` at the end of the date format. Since your date has a `Z`, it is in UTC. So you can use:

```
[dateFormatter setTimeZone: [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation: @"UTC"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
```

Answer (score 0):

the string value which you are trying to convert to NSDate is incorrect.
"2011-11-10T07:22:59Z" 
it should have a timezone difference value in place of "Z" to make it compatible to date formatter's format.
e.g. 2011-11-10T07:22:59+0430