# Google JSON API output for iPhone Time zone

Tags: iphone, json, time, google-calendar-api

When I read the start time for an event using the JSON output for Google calendar I get the time in this format "2009-03-05T10:46:25.245Z". How can I convert this to meaning full date and time in iPhone SDK?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this post has your answer: [Nil NSDate when trying to get date from UTC string in zulu time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263455/nil-nsdate-when-trying-to-get-date-from-utc-string-in-zulu-time)

This seems to work for me:

```
NSString *timeValue = @"2009-03-05T10:46:25.245Z";
NSDateFormatter* df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
NSDate* date = [df dateFromString:[timeValue stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"Z" withString:@"-0000"]];
NSLog(@"The date is: %@",date);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately no luck. NSString *timeValue has the value 2009-03-05T10:46:25.245Z. Can you give me sample code to convert  this variable....appreciate it .

Comment: Take a look at my edit above, I just run it in the sim and it worked fine. The key is replacing the Z with "-0000".