# iPhone and iPad iOS 6 SDK difference?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios6, nsdateformatter

I developed an app for iPhone, and I am having problems when running it on an iPad in compatibility mode (iPhone-only app).

The `NSDateFormatter` class is behaving wrong:

```
NSString *dateString = @"2013-01-18T14:55:50Z";
NSDateFormatter* dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"];
NSDate *theDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];
```

When running this code on iPhone, I get the correct date in `theDate`, while when I run this same code on iPad (3rd gen, in my case), I always get a `nil` value.

Is this right?

Comment: Can you confirm both your iPhone and iPad settings are same? Like both have same timezone etc..

Comment: if you use the UIdatepicker then it difference in ios 5 and ios 6 date picker :)

Comment: Yes, they are. But this conversion should not be time-zone dependent.

Comment: I am not using `UIDatePicker`. I am just parsing a string date into an `NSDate` object.

Comment: @marzapower I can understand. Just for confirmation can you go to Settings - General - International - Region Format. And confirm both have same?

Comment: I think it is the problem with formatting, same question has been asked by someone here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263455/nil-nsdate-when-trying-to-get-date-from-utc-string-in-zulu-time I hope this helps

Comment: @Rushi: they are the same.

Comment: @Ankur: the problem here is that the same API works in two different ways on the same iOS 6.0.1 SDK.

Comment: If you've found a reproducible bug then log it with https://bugreport.apple.com otherwise it will never be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The NSDateFormatter takes into consideration the settings on your device such as your region format(locale) set in international tab and the 12 or 24 hour format set in your device. Check both the region format and time format of your iPad. Maybe its in 12 hour format!!

Comment: There is the same region and time format on both devices. The difference is not that the time changes, but that I get a `nil` value on the 3rd gen iPad.