# NSDateFormatter Returns Nil with Seemingly Correct Format String

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I'm using an NSDateFormatter to generate NSDate objects from server time strings. We're using ISO-8601 Extended, and below is a method I have that returns a date formatter that handles the transformation:

```
+ (NSDateFormatter *) dateFormatter {
    NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [NSDateFormatter new];
    dateFormatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ";
    dateFormatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier: @"en_US_POSIX"];
    return dateFormatter;
}
```

However, when I use that code, the below assert fails:

```
NSDateFormatter * dateFormatter = [MyClass dateFormatter]; 
                                            //    "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
_testDateObject = [dateFormatter dateFromString: @"2016-01-18'T'16:31:16.401Z"];
NSParameterAssert(_testDateObject);
```

What's wrong with the date formatting string that I'm using? I've tried variations on it (such as escaping the literals), and none of them produce a valid `NSDate`.

**EDIT**
My original post included the incorrect formatting string I was using. As pointed out by rmaddy, I should be using `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ`, which I am.

Comment: Read the documentation for the date format specifiers. Read what you should be using for year, day, and fractional seconds..

Comment: Closely related: [Nil NSDate when trying to get date from UTC string in Zulu time](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1263455)

Comment: Specification http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-dates.html#Date_Field_Symbol_Table `DD` is day of the year (1..356). `YYYY` is not calendar year. `sss` are seconds. `SSS` are fractional seconds.

Comment: What confuses me is that the answer there doesn't answer this question. I still get a nil result, even when the datestring is yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ or yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZZZZZ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your input string, `"2016-01-18'T'16:31:16.401Z"`, doesn't match your format.

In a format string, the `'` character begins and ends an escaped sequence of characters. The format substring `'T'` matches the input substring `T`, **not** the input substring `'T'`. Since nothing in your format string matches the single quotes in your input, the conversion fails.

If you really want your input to contain single quotes, you must use doubled single quotes in your format to match them, **and** use single quotes to escape the `T`:

```
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'''T'''HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")

let date = formatter.dateFromString("2016-01-18'T'16:31:16.401Z")

// Result:
"Jan 18, 2016, 10:31 AM"
```

Comment: That works when I tried your suggestion! Given that I can't change the format of the string coming from the server, what's your suggestion to parsing the date? I tried using "yyyy-MM-dd''T''HH:mm:ss.SSSZ" (note the two single quotes around the T) but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Thanks Rob, that fixed my issue! I'm curious why I need an extra pair to escape the sequence as opposed to two. Is this because the parser needs an additional set of quotes to know it should escape the second pair of quotes?

Comment: `''` in the format matches `'` in the input. `'T'` in the format matches `T` in the input. you can't share a `'` between the two patterns. Each pattern must be self-contained.